# How to specify the wifi network to connect and avoid any other (for raspberry pi 0w)

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-zero

I am using raspeberry pi 0W (Debian) to connect to a specific WiFi network, the problem is that sometimes it connects to other networks (open wifi networks).

I do not want to edit ***wpa_supplicant.conf*** every time it discover another network.

I need to set the network and keep this one as the only one RPI would connect.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a special SSID (WiFi network) to the `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Add these details of your SSID to that config file like:

```
network={
    ssid="testing"
    psk="testingPassword"
}
```

You can find more about it [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md).

---

> I do not want to edit wpa_supplicant.conf every time it discover
>   another network.

Add these lines at the end of `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
network={
    key_mgmt=NONE
    priority=-999
}
```

You can find more about it [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=107852).

Comment: The OP never want to connect to another (open) network so *these lines at the end* are not needed.

Comment: You actually *don't need* (more precisely: **can't use**) wpa_supplicant to connect to an unencrypted open wireless network -- which is part of why public wifi providers usually post the password, rather than use no password (WPA requires a password, though WPS can get around that).  So you may have to do something with dhcpcd.conf too.